# how to display jquery loop in ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display ajax response output ,which is an array , it output is looking good in console.log ,but not getting displayed in  resp div .

Here is jquery ajax code

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#demo").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"response.php",
            type:"post",
            data:{ "a":"a"},
                success: function(obj){
                var json = $.parseJSON(obj);
                $.each(json,function(k,v){
                    $(".resp").html("<li>"+v+"</li>");
                    console.log("<li>"+v+"</li>");
                }); 
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        })
 });
});
```

here is response.php

```
$a=array("1"=>"a","2"=>"b","3"=>"c","4"=>"d","5"=>"e","6"=>"f","7"=>"g","8"=>"h","9"=>"i","10"=>"j");
echo json_encode($a);
```

here is html

```
<div><button id="demo">Click me</button></div>
<div class="resp"></div>
```

Comment: `$(".resp").append("<li>"+v+"</li>");` instead of `$(".resp").html("<li>"+v+"</li>");`

Comment: great it works, but why it is so,why .html no working

Comment: because .html will replace all the html first and then add the new one. while .append is adding to next not removing anything.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Anant

Comment: one more thing @Anant , i also want to add <ul> tag in that code

Comment: yes only first time is it possible

Comment: is it not possible in jquery code ,like <li > tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do `.append()` instead of `.html`:-**

```
$(".resp").append("<li>"+v+"</li>");
```

Note:-  When you are using `.html()` then first it removes the complete `html` attached with the corresponding element and then add the new one.

While `.append()` is not going to remove anything, its just append the new one to the existing html of that element.

**As you asked that you want to append it inside `<ul></ul>` then you can do it in two ways:-**

1.`<div class="resp"><ul></ul></div>` and then `$(".resp ul").append("<li>"+v+"</li>");`

2.Directly use this code,No other changes are required:-

```
success: function(obj){ var json = $.parseJSON(obj); var data = '<ul>'; $.each(json,function(k,v){ data += "<li>"+v+"</li>"; }); data += '</ul>'; $(".resp ul").append(data); },
```